# Eligibility requirement for "New Brunswick PNP"

Tags: canada, immigration

This [link](http://www.canadavisa.com/eligibility-requirements-new-brunswick-nominee-program.html) provides detailed eligibility requirements for the various categories of the NBPNP.

I have a question from below para:

> Candidates are assigned a score based on the information provided, after which they are assessed according to the following criteria:
>
> - Highest score;
> - Evidence of training and experience in a high priority sector as
>     determined by the province;
> - Demonstrated ability **to become economically established** in the
>     province; and
> - The **likelihood of positively contributing to the provincial labour
>
>     market**.

Being as `software engineer` in IT background, I would like to understand:

1) How do I interpret this statement: **to become economically established in the province**?

2) How do I interpret this statement: **likelihood of positively contributing to the provincial labor market**?

Comment: @mkennedy Do you think you can help me on this?

Comment: I don't have any insight on these. I think they mean 1) have enough money to get set up and working without issue, and 2) being a good worker who will remain employed and contributing to the economy and bring good skills.

Answer (score 4):

The best I can find is that there are no legal definitions for the terms you highlighted.  More specifically as mentioned in the [operational information for CIC](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/resources/manuals/op/op07b-eng.pdf)

> There is no definition in the legislation of “become economically established,” leaving the term open to interpretation. There is also no indication of the exact moment when an applicant must become economically established: immediately upon landing or after an initial period of adjustment. However, it is clear, from the way in which the term is used throughout the economic classes, that to become economically established means to join and participate in the labour market in Canada. It is also clear that the selection criteria do not apply to the provincial nominee class in the same way as they apply to federal skilled workers and that it is the overall intention of the legislation and the Federal-Provincial-Territorial agreements to allow the provinces some latitude in their nomination decisions.

But there is another [operational bulletin 499](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/resources/manuals/bulletins/2013/ob499.asp) which clarifies it somewhat:

> An indicator of the ability to become economically established is the applicant’s intention and ability to enter the labour market in order to fully support him/herself. If the visa officer is not satisfied that the individual intends to enter the labour market, a refusal of the application should be considered. Part-time or casual work which would not generate enough income to fully support the applicant may not meet this requirement.

So if you use this as a guideline for "becoming economically established" you can infer that "positively contributing" implies that you either fill positions necessary to alleviate the labour shortage (if one exists) in the specific field or create positions to be filled in the Province but that would be more for business PNP.

Comment: How can the term be open to interpretation? At least the immigration department should have its specific meaning

Comment: Join and participate in labour market? How do I understand this?

Comment: Means that until it is adjudicated the term is interpreted by individual immigration official to the best of their understanding.

Comment: Either as an employer or a worker.

Comment: Why are you a good candidate for NB? `For past 10 yrs, I worked for IBM and then for company(CA Technologies). My financial & technical background makes me reliable to get setup and work without issue. I shall consistently upgrade my skills to join and contribute to the labor market of this province.` Do u suggest any improvements in  this answer?